# How to read through all Labels in a page in Xamarin in order to save them into SQlite?

Tags: xamarin

I want to read through all Labels into an SQLite file. Labels in each Frame should be in a row of SQLite table.

[image]

[image]

In each Frame, time text goes to Time column and activity text goes into Activity column of the table.

I don't have problem in writing data into SQLite. My problem is about reading through Labels.

Comment: the user can't change the data in the Labels, so they have the data that YOU put in them, so you should be able to track that data as you create the labels.  "Reading" the Labels is the wrong approach.

Comment: The user adds those data (time, activity) using a popup. After that, those data needs to be stored somewhere. Do you mean that I add those data into sqlite as the user clicks the button to add frames?

Comment: you should capture the data from the popup in some sort of data structure, and use *that* to both populate your UI and update your db